# How to remote / connect hbase table from hive from different computer

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata, apache-zookeeper

I confused to connect hbase table from different computer using Hive.

I am also have try this hive query :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tabel_apik(key string, val1 string)STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "web:teks")TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_tabel");
```

how to create a hive table, if I have hbase table in `192.168.88.123`
and I will create hive table from hbase in `192.168.88.101`

Thank you

Comment: okay thank you Alex Jolig, Im newbie in stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 0):

- You need to establish a connection to 192.168.88.123 from
  192.168.88.101 using JDBC or ODBC or thrift drivers.
- Please ensure for starting hive server and hbase server before you start connection with the other host.
  [Hive Server Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer)